# using variables to create data object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I have this code snippet

```
      splitTopic = splitTopic.slice(1, splitTopic.length);
      let rawData = data.toString("utf8")
      let correctData = !isNaN(rawData) ? (parseFloat(rawData) % 1 === 0 ? parseInt(rawData) : parseFloat(rawData)) : rawData;
      let datapoint = splitTopic[3]
      let parsedData = { dataPoint: correctData }
```

What is the correct way of referencing dataPoint to create my data object parsedData.

I tried:

```
let parseData = {splitTopic[3]: correctData}
```

But it doesn't like this also

Comment: `{[splitTopic[3]]: correctData}`. Use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#bracket_notation).

Comment: `let parsedData = { [dataPoint]: correctData }`. Wrap `dataPoint` in `[]` to make it a dynamic key